# Type mismatch: cannot convert from AwsClientBuilder to AmazonCloudFormation

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jar, aws-cloudformation

Hi I am trying to use the [AWS java sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java) for to create an *aws cloud formation*. My JDK version is **1.8** and I have imported the following jars in my java application

1. [aws-java-sdk-support-1.11.155.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-support/1.11.155)
2. [aws-java-sdk-logs-1.11.155.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-logs/1.11.155)
3. [aws-java-sdk-1.11.155.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk/1.11.155)
4. [aws-java-sdk-cloudformation-1.11.155.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-cloudformation/1.11.155)
5. [aws-java-sdk-core-1.11.155.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk-core/1.11.155)

I am trying to initialize my amazonCloudFormation variable *amazonClient* but I am getting the following error

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AwsClientBuilder to AmazonCloudFormation
```

My code is attached below

```
 public AmazonCloudFormation amazonClient;
 BasicAWSCredentials  credentials=new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey,secretKey);     
 amazonClient=AwsClientBuilder
             .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials) );
```

Can somebody let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: I dont see static method `withCredentials` on `AwsClientBuilder`. According to AWS documentation you have to use this builder: `AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();`.

Comment: Can you provide the link to the aws documentation where it is mentioned?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/AmazonCloudFormationClient.html#AmazonCloudFormationClient-com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials-

Comment: @tsolakp It looks like it working. Canyou post your answer so that I can accept the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/cloudformation/AmazonCloudFormationClient.html#AmazonCloudFormationClient-com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials-) you have to use this builder: `AmazonCloudFormationClientBuilder.standard().withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCredentials)).build();`.